# Network Manager overriding /etc/hosts file

Tags: linux, hosts-file

I believe the network manager service on Oracle Linux 6 is causing problems for the clouder-scm-agent which is running on my machine. 
The clouder-scm-agent starts up on the server ip it resolves from looking at /etc/hosts and on restart the network manager seems to be adding unwanted entry in the hosts file causing my **cloudera-scm-agent to start on 127.0.0.1:9000 port rather than 10.240.190.43:9000** on which the cloudera-scm-server excepts it to start on.

The reason i want to disable network manager is because it seems to be modifying the /etc/hosts file even if i have set read only permission to my /etc/hosts. My /etc/hosts looks like this

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
10.240.190.43   slc04vvo.internal.com   slc04vvvo
```

on restarting Oracle Linux Server 6 it adds

```
127.0.0.1       slc04vvo localhost.localdomain localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

My hostname is

```
hostname
slc04vvo
```

Of the two additions happening here , i would not want the hostname to be an existing 127.0.0.1 entry and also i dont want the ipv6 localhost6 entry to be added.

Anyone has any pointers on why this is happening ?

Is there a good documentation some one can point as to what is the role of network manager service in linux and if i disable network manager service across reboots what are the other steps i need to take (what other files i need to modify with static information ) so that i am not affected with disabling network manager.

thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the wrong solution.  You'll want to modify the config file for the clouder-scm-agent not the hosts file.

Comment: Looks like the settings file is /etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini

Comment: Hi , yes i have seen this file in which i can change few properties , but i believe the first problem i need to solve is the automatic overwrite of /etc/hosts which leads my agent to be started on ipv6 address or the 127.0.0.1 address. How would i go about making sure in linux the hosts file is not overwritten everytime i restart ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are being bitten by [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=648725) (like the rest of us). Oracle/Red Hat are two years off the pace at picking this up - if anybody's running a recent (! fc13+) version of fedora to confirm NetworkManager has improved, 'twould be useful feedback.

In general, the NetworkManager doc is on the [gnome site](https://live.gnome.org/NetworkManager), and should be definitive, but they'll be more focussed on the current bleeding edge rather than the versions we're stuck with in the enterprise/mainstream/stable distros.